# Using NHibernate to report a table with two sums

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have three tables: People, Purchases, Payments with 1-to-many relationships between People and Purchases, and People and Payments.

I want to generate a report of People showing the sum of their Purchases and Payments.

I can easily generate a report for all people showing the sum of the payments or purchases, vis:

```
var query = 
  DetachedCriteria.For<People>("People")
  .CreateAlias("Payments", "paymentsMade");

query.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
  .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Id"), "Id")
  .Add(Projections.Sum("paymentsMade.Amount"), "TotalPayments")
```

Can I do this in a single query in NHibernate?  Either using the criteria API (preferred) or HQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var query = @"select
                (select sum(pu.Amount) from Purchase pu where pu.People.Id = ppl.Id),
                (select sum(pa.Amount) from Payments pa where pa.People.Id = ppl.Id) 
              from People ppl";

var results = session
                .CreateQuery(query)
                .List();
```

Or perhaps using [**ad-hoc mapping**](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2010/06/29/ad-hoc-mapping-with-nhibernate.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+LosTechies+%28LosTechies%29):

```
public class BulkReport
{
    public double Purchases { get; set; }
    public double Payments  { get; set; }
}

var results = session
                .CreateQuery(query)
                .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(BulkReport)))
                .List<BulkReport>();
```

Another option would be using [**MultiQueries**](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/05/NHibernateMutliQuerySupport.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  Do you know if it is possible to do the same thing within a DetachedCriteria?  The API I am working with expects a DetachedCriteria rather than an HQL query.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is, but I avoid Criteria like the plague, so I couldn't help you here. x)